# how to numbered ascending the select results from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this a simple php mysqli select code and I want to numbered each result like this:

```
echo $row['city'] .'-'.$row['number'].'<br>'; // $row['number'] = 1
echo $row['city'] .'-'.$row['number'].'<br>'; // $row['number'] = 2
echo $row['city'] .'-'.$row['number'].'<br>'; // $row['number'] = 3
```

How can I count the results? I can't do this whit ORDER BY id
Thanks!

Comment: You question is vague. What is your current output? What is your expected output? Where is your query?

Comment: I want to give a  ascending number for each result!

Comment: Is there any iteration involved?

Comment: In that case, just from what you show here, you might be showing the same thing 3 times. Anyway.. do you know how to increment a number?

Comment: Yes i know, but i don't want to put a for instructon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not telling us very much about your context, but I will try to guess what you need. It sounds that you need a numerical index for each row that you would get straight from your MySQL result set.

Considering that current query might be something like

```
SELECT city FROM cities
```

You might try something like

```
SELECT city, @number:=@number+1 AS number FROM `cities`, (SELECT @number:=0) AS t
```

And in the "number" column you will have a numerical index, starting from 1 and incremented for each row.